# mysqld service won't start

Tags: mysql, innodb, fedora-28

After Fedora 28 decided to upgrade mysql-community packages to 8.0 (latest) ,I realized my application was failing and had to downgrade to mysql 5.27.2

Of course my db files (.idb) were the same (altered by mysql 8.0).
When starting mysql 5.27 service, it fails. I have read the log file /var/log/mysqld.log and found this:

> InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in
>   file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!

Answer (score 27):

This problem was solved **removing all database** files:

```
 sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
```

**Please be aware you will lose every database in the server by doing this!!!
In my case I had a dump and i could restore.**

Comment: The Upgrade Notes are clear -- you cannot go back to 5.7 without reloading the data !

Comment: Do you really read the upgrade notes of every package updated in a complete OS release?

Comment: You are trying to Downgrade: "had to rollback to mysql 5.27.2".

Comment: On a mac is it possible to use Time Machine to restore the contents of the mysql data folder? (It's a development machine not production! And just an ordinary laptop not a server).

Comment: Wow. Genius solution </irony>

Comment: Glad it helps @ManuelSchneid3r. 
 Makes sense it's the most upvoted.

Comment: Usually you do not want to lose all data. So I don't get the upvotes.

Comment: An equivalent of this worked for me on OS X. `sudo rm -rm /opt/homebrew/var/mysql` and then reinstall mysql@5.7 via brew.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you are using the MySQL version 8.0 client specifically to avoid this error

**RCA**
1.You attempted to start a newer version of mysql server with mysqld_safe(ver5)  instead of the version 8.0

**Solution**

```
export MYSQL_8_HOME=/path/to/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64 #e.g /usr/local/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64
cd $MYSQL_8_HOME # where is the dorectory mysql v8.0 was installed.
bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --datadir=/path/to/data/mysql
```

Just for added measure, you might consider updating your PATH variable to prefix it with the newer version of MySQL programs like this

```
export PATH=$MYSQL_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

before starting mysqld_safe