# InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000

Tags: mysql, windows, spring-boot, docker

I run my docker-compose file mysql last version in windows. But i want to run mysql version5.7 and i am getting an error.

> InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

volumes:
  db_data:
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: &connectionUrl jdbc:mysql://${DB_CONNECTION_IP:localhost}:${DB_CONNECTION_PORT:3306}/masa?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: &username ${DB_CONNECTION_USERNAME:root}
    password: &password ${DB_CONNECTION_PASSWORD:root}
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I solved it by removing the container, the image and the volume and running `docker-compose up` atain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqld service won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469060/mysqld-service-wont-start)