# why does oracle community image 8.0 crash immediately every time?

Tags: mysql, docker

I downloaded a fresh image to run mysql 8.0 but when I start it up it says

```
2023-08-03 10:37:26 [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.34-1.2.13-server
2023-08-03 10:37:26 mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1.
2023-08-03 10:37:26 mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
2023-08-03 10:37:26 [Entrypoint] ERROR: Unable to start MySQL. Please check your configuration.
2023-08-03 10:37:26 [Entrypoint]
```

and exits.  How do I make the community image run?

if I specify

```bash
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash --name=mysql80-3 \
   --mount type=bind,src=/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/marketplace.akc.org/my.cnf,dst=/etc/my.cnf \
   --mount type=bind,src=/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/temp,dst=/var/lib/mysql \
   -d container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/community-server:8.0
```

then it stays running but I am trying to fix whatever the problem is that makes it fail without all these arguments

/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/marketplace.akc.org/my.cnf:

```
innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
```

Comment: "*`2023-08-03 10:37:26 mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1.`*" - Without seeing this file, we cannot diagnose the problem. Please [edit] the post and add the content of `/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/marketplace.akc.org/my.cnf`.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes the question is updated with the file contents now

Comment: Please add `[mysqld]` as first line in the `.cnf` file and retry.

Comment: @Turing85 that fixes it for the community image, but the image I am trying to run starts and then crashes right away with `2023-08-03 13:47:15 2023-08-03T17:47:15.338208Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!`

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that there is already data present in the `data` mount (i.e. `/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/temp`). Deleting this directory on the host may solve the issue (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469060/mysqld-service-wont-start)). This, however, means that all data currently stored in the database is lost.

Comment: @Turing85 but if I don't mount `/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/temp`, the container crashes, so if I delete it I cannot run the container at all.  Is the problem that the default data directory is corrupted?

Comment: My guess is that the configuration in the `.cnf` file is not consistent with the configuration of the database (`Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!`). So it seems that we can either set the flag with a fresh (empty) data directory, or we remove the flag. Take this with a grain of salt, I am only deducing, I am not an expert wrt. mysql.

Comment: @Turing85 I agree because when I run the comm image with a custom data directory and a custom cnf file the container runs but then if I try to start the proj mysql container that is part of my laravel project, it goes back to crashing with the same errors.  Based on what you just said, I am changing my `docker-compose.yml`:   volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql` to `/Users/bmr/Desktop/Work/temp` since that allows the community image to run. The database container still crashes with the same errors, maybe it's `[ERROR] InnoDB: Error in creating ./ibdata1: probably out of disk space`

Comment: @Turing85 in reference to my last comment, I see that `/usr/local/var/mysql` has 3100 error log files in it so deleting them would free up a lot of disk space... BUT according to https://serverfault.com/questions/82093/is-it-safe-to-remove-the-bin-files-that-are-generated-by-mysql if I delete the files manually it will crash mysql but I cannot connect to mysql to execute the proper command so I am stuck for a way to erase the files and fix the problem they cause.